# Nivo Slider, use something other than title attribute for caption?

Tags: nivo-slider

Is there a way to use a different HTML markup to populate the caption text in a Nivo Slider? For search engines I don't want the content to be stuffed in the title attribute of the image tags.

Currently:

`<img src="/image.jpg" title="Blah blah paragraph..." />`

I would like something like this:

`<img src="/image.jpg" /><div class="nivo-title">Blah blah paragraph...</div>`

Answer (score 4):

There's an easier way to do it.

NivoSlider supports HTML captions.  See documentation here:

http://docs.dev7studios.com/jquery-plugins/nivo-slider

Set up your html caption in a div outside the #slider with display:none like this:

```
  <div id="htmlcaption" class="nivo-html-caption" style="display:none">
     <strong>This</strong> is an example of a <em>HTML</em> caption. 
   It even has <a href="#">a link</a>.
  </div>
```

Now, in your slide image set the title attribute to the id of the caption element:

```
<img src="images/slide2.jpg" alt="" title="#htmlcaption" />
```

When the slider runs, it finds the referenced caption and copies it to the active caption div and animates it for you.  No need to change the javascript at all.

Comment: This solution uses the capability of the library rather than changing the code which may lead to upgrade/compabilitiy pain.

Answer (score 2):

Open up your jquery.nivo.slider.js, on line 94 is the processCaption function.  You can change this instead of looking at the 'title' attribute to anything you want.

For example

```
    var processCaption = function(settings){
        var nivoCaption = $('.nivo-caption', slider);
        if(vars.currentImage.parent().find(".nivo-title").html() != '' && vars.currentImage.find(".nivo-title").html() != undefined){
            var title = vars.currentImage.find(".nivo-title").html();
            if(title.substr(0,1) == '#') title = $(title).html();   
            ...
        }
    }
```

Comment: I might be missing something, but since currentImage is not a referencing a container there is nothing to 'find' using the find method.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Alexander for pointing me in the right direction! The following worked:

```
var processCaption = function(settings){
        var nivoCaption = $('.nivo-caption', slider);
        var nivoMyTitle = vars.currentImage.parent('.nivo-imageLink').find('.nivo-title'); //class of container with paragraph
        if(nivoMyTitle.html() != '' && nivoMyTitle.html() != undefined){
        var title = nivoMyTitle.html();
        if(title.substr(0,1) == '#') title = $(title).html();
```

The HTML:

```
<a href=""><img src="/image.jpg" /><div class="nivo-title">Blah blah paragraph...</div></a>
```

The CSS:

```
.nivo-title{display:none;} .nivo-caption p{font-size:12px;}
```